# How to use criteria with enums from TypeScript service?

Tags: jhipster

I have a criteria that is roughly like this :

```
public class DocuSignTemplateDefinitionCriteria implements Serializable {

    public static class DocuSignTemplateTypeFilter extends Filter<DocuSignTemplateType> {
    }

    private DocuSignTemplateTypeFilter templateType;
    private LongFilter sponsorLevelId;
    private LongFilter languageId;
    private LongFilter eventId;
```

From the TypeScript service, I can use the query with all the simple types (in this example, longs):

```
this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}languageId.equals=2&sponsorLevelId.equals=4&eventId.equals=1001`)
```

But I can't figure out how to query the enum `DocuSignTemplateType`. I've used several syntaxes (below is one example), but I can't get it right.

```
this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}?languageId.equals=2&sponsorLevelId.equals=4&eventId.equals=1001&templateType.equals=DocuSignTemplateType.SPONSOR_AGREEMENT`)
```

Any idea ? Any example on how to archieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: If I look at the generated JAVA tests, I would say it's `templateType.equals=SPONSOR_AGREEMENT` without the enum class name. See [here](https://sonarcloud.io/component?id=io.github.jhipster.sample%3Ajhipster-sample-application%3Asrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fio%2Fgithub%2Fjhipster%2Fsample%2Fweb%2Frest%2FFieldTestServiceClassEntityResourceIntTest.java&line=2324) for an example.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's working. I've tried all sorts of complex syntax, but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comment, it must be `templateType.equals=SPONSOR_AGREEMENT`without the enum class name.